# Eloquent and Laravel, get the MONTH and YEAR of a datetime

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent query that is giving me an error with the ´ ´ that Laravel put on it. If I copy-paste the same query as SQL in my database it works perfect, but I don't know hot the proceed with MONTH() and YEAR() correctly in Eloquent. I have this:

```
$datos = MyModel::select([
'id',
'period',
'MONTH(time_table.period) AS month',
'YEAR(time_table.period) AS year'])
->get();
```

and `period` is a datetime value. I need to retrieve the month and year of that 'period' value.

What can I do?

EDIT:

The error in the app is (with the original values):

(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MONTH(admin_fijacion_anteriores.periodo)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id_fijacion` as `id`, `admin_distribuidoras`.`nombre` as `nombre_distribuidora`, `admin_licitaciones`.`nombre` as `nombre_licitacion`, `admin_generadoras`.`nombre` as `nombre_generadora`, `admin_bloques`.`nombre` as `nombre_bloques`, `periodo`, `energia`, `potencia`, `MONTH(admin_fijacion_anteriores`.`periodo)` as `mes`, `YEAR(admin_fijacion_anteriores`.`periodo)` as `anio` from `admin_fijacion_anteriores` inner join `admin_distribuidoras` on `admin_fijacion_anteriores`.`distribuidora_id` = `admin_distribuidoras`.`id_distribuidora` inner join `admin_licitaciones` on `admin_fijacion_anteriores`.`licitacion_id` = `admin_licitaciones`.`id_licitacion` inner join `admin_generadoras` on `admin_fijacion_anteriores`.`generadora_id` = `admin_generadoras`.`id_generadora` inner join `admin_bloques` on `admin_fijacion_anteriores`.`bloque_id` = `admin_bloques`.`id_bloque`)

and the code of my real Eloquent query is:

```
$datos = AdminFijacionAnteriore::select([
    'id_fijacion AS id',
    'admin_distribuidoras.nombre as nombre_distribuidora',
    'admin_licitaciones.nombre as nombre_licitacion',
    'admin_generadoras.nombre as nombre_generadora',
    'admin_bloques.nombre as nombre_bloques',
    'periodo',
    'energia',
    'potencia',
    'MONTH(admin_fijacion_anteriores.periodo) AS mes',
    'YEAR(admin_fijacion_anteriores.periodo) AS anio'])
    ->join('admin_distribuidoras', 'admin_fijacion_anteriores.distribuidora_id', '=', 'admin_distribuidoras.id_distribuidora')
    ->join('admin_licitaciones', 'admin_fijacion_anteriores.licitacion_id', '=', 'admin_licitaciones.id_licitacion')
    ->join('admin_generadoras', 'admin_fijacion_anteriores.generadora_id', '=', 'admin_generadoras.id_generadora')
    ->join('admin_bloques', 'admin_fijacion_anteriores.bloque_id', '=', 'admin_bloques.id_bloque')
    ->get();
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Let me edit the question with the error:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`selectRaw()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_selectRaw) instead of `select()`.

In your case :

```
$datos = MyModel::selectRaw('
    id,
    period,
    MONTH(time_table.period) AS month,
    YEAR(time_table.period) AS year
')->get();
```

---

But in my opinion, the correct solution to your problem would be to use [date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) on your model, and then simply call `$datos->period->month`

Comment: Thanks, this did the job.